# Laravel resource calls wrong method

Tags: php, laravel

I'm going nuts since hours with Laravel.

This is my `web.php` file:

```
// Admin
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'admin'], 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {

  Route::resource('cities', 'CitiesController');
  Route::resource('stores', 'StoresController');

});
```

I'm accessing `http://localhost:3000/admin/cities/create` and I get an error from the `show` method! Why the URL is calling the `show` method instead of `create`? And why if I remove the `Route::resource` and replace with verbose routes, it works? That's crazy.

[image]

**UPDATE**

My `route:list`:

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin                     | admin            | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController@index                   | web,auth,admin |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/cities              | cities.index     | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CityController@index                        | web,auth,admin |
|        | POST      | admin/cities              | cities.store     | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CityController@store                        | web,auth,admin |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/cities/create       | cities.create    | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CityController@create                       | web,auth,admin |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/cities/{city}       | cities.show      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CityController@show                         | web,auth,admin |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/cities/{city}       | cities.update    | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CityController@update                       | web,auth,admin |
|        | DELETE    | admin/cities/{city}       | cities.destroy   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CityController@destroy                      | web,auth,admin |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/cities/{city}/edit  | cities.edit      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CityController@edit                         | web,auth,admin |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/stores              | stores.index     | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\StoreController@index                       | web,auth,admin |
|        | POST      | admin/stores              | stores.store     | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\StoreController@store                       | web,auth,admin |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/stores/create       | stores.create    | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\StoreController@create                      | web,auth,admin |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/stores/{store}      | stores.show      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\StoreController@show                        | web,auth,admin |
|        | DELETE    | admin/stores/{store}      | stores.destroy   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\StoreController@destroy                     | web,auth,admin |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/stores/{store}      | stores.update    | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\StoreController@update                      | web,auth,admin |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/stores/{store}/edit | stores.edit      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\StoreController@edit                        | web,auth,admin |
```

Comment: Can you share the (relevant part of) the output of `php artisan route:list` and the create route handler?

Comment: are you making get request on this url http://localhost:3000/admin/cities/create

Comment: You have route `admin/cities/create` and `admin/cities/{city}` which creates ambiguity for Route Controller as `create` is argument for `{city}`. And that is why call to `show` method

Comment: how does it happen it should be POST not `| GET|HEAD  | admin/cities/{city}       | cities.show `

Comment: @ZaheerAttar those routes are generated by `Route::resource`. How to fix? @Ajay it should not be POST the `show`.

Comment: @FredCollins Here.. this might help you.. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#restful-naming-resource-routes

Comment: @ZaheerAttar how does that relate to my issue? I think that's just for the names of the route.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your routes, check carefully there is space after `create` if there is space after create then it will hit `show` method or some spelling mistake.

Comment: @GovindSamrow this issue is driving me nuts. What you mean if there's a space after create? There's no space. It's quite weird that `Route::resource` method is buggy right? I don't understand why it works if I have only one resource and if I add a new one, it stops working the `create` action.

Comment: Did you get the solution???

Answer (score -1):

Make your show store route like this:

```
Route::get('/store/{store}', 'StoresController@show')->name('stores.show');
```

Comment: I want to keep `/stores/`.